# AtomエディタでHTMLコードを書いたがwebブラウザ上で画像が表示されない

Tags: html

webブラウザ上で画像が表示されないのはなぜでしょうか。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「認識されない」というのは、どういう意味ですか？
　Atomで質問のコードを表示した際の話であれば、Atomの画面のスクリーンショットを質問に追加してください。
　Atomエディタは様々な機能があり、パッケージをインストールすることで機能追加できたりします。なので、どのような状態（どんなパッケージがインストールされている等）でAtomを使っているのかが判らないと、回答してもらえないと思います。

Comment: WebブラウザーではなくAtomエディタ上に画像を表示したいのですか？ 当初書かれていたHTMLコード片を削除されたということは、質問者さんとしてはHTMLとは無関係の質問という判断ですか？ 第三者からみて何を尋ねたいのかはっきりしません。

Comment: 単純に、指定された場所(index.htmlがあるフォルダの中のimgサブフォルダ)に指定されたファイル(taro.png)が無いのでは？ Windowsの記事ですが参考に。[Atomの画像表示](https://teratail.com/questions/65320)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントしたのと同じ考え方の、別の言い方になりますが、`index.html`ファイルの置き場所が違います。

index.htmlファイルは、imgフォルダの中ではなく、一つ上のMyPortfolioフォルダの中(かつfavicon.icoと同じフォルダ)でなければなりません。